# How to save entered text in JS/Html

Tags: javascript, html

How do i save entered/ inputted text using JavaScript/ html.

What do I want:
Name or code etc to be entered in a box (prompt box eksample) and then I want it to be displayed/ printed on the page and I want it to remain there so other people that visit can see it.

What I have:
I have code that shows a prompt box where you can enter text then displays it in green. However what i want is for the entered text to remain on the website for others to see...

```
  function mobCode() {
mobCode = prompt("Insert Code", "Code here");
document.getElementById("mC").innerHTML = mobCode;
document.getElementById("mC").style.color="green";
}
<p id="mC"> Mob Code </p>
<button type="button" onclick="mobCode()"> Click to Add </button>
```

Comment: You need to create a server that you can POST the text to.

Comment: You first need to learn and understand the concept of client and servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will probably have to do is write a script that will send the entered input to a database you build which can store that information,and then have your js access the database to display it in a certain area of your page.

Check out this Q & A one of the answers is a nice article to help explain the idea behind it: [Send data from javascript to a mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412505/send-data-from-javascript-to-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal easier with persistence of the data, instead of setting up database and using server side script you can look at Facebook's [Parse](https://parse.com/). The free plan is quite usefull for small projects. There is a [JavaScript SDK](https://parse.com/products/javascript) that can be used directly from your javascript code.

Also you can view statistics from the Parse dashboard.

Here is some saple code for example:

```
// Create a new Parse object
var Post = new ParseObject("Post");
var post = new Post();

// Save it to Parse
post.save({"title": "Hello World"}).then(function(object) {
  alert("Yay! It worked!");
});
```