# How to take screenshot of game div in phaser

Tags: javascript, screenshot, phaser-framework

I am using this code now, but it returns a blank transparent image:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#t").click(function() {
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#bracelet_maker"), 
         { onrendered: function(canvas){ 
            src = canvas.toDataURL();
            window.open(src); } });
    });
});
```

If I use `game.canvas.toDataUrl();` it returns a black image.

This is how the game is started in #bracelet_maker div

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(width,height,Phaser.AUTO,"bracelte_canvas",{
    preload:preload,
    create:create,
    update:update  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Phaser.AUTO` will allow either `Phaser.WEBGL` or `Phaser.CANVAS` be used, depending upon what your browser supports.

If you switch over to `Phaser.CANVAS` when creating your `new Phaser.Game` you should be able to use access the `canvas`.

For example, within Phaser by binding off the <kbd>S</kbd> key:

```
function create() {
    // ...
    var screenshotKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.S);
    screenshotKey.onDown.add(function () { window.open(game.canvas.toDataURL()); 
}
```

There's also [`preserveDrawingBuffer`](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Game.html#preserveDrawingBuffer) which should allow you capture from WebGL as well, but it needs to be [set early on in the process](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/987).

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload: preload, create: create, update: update
});
game.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
```

Comment: James Skemp thanx alot bro

Comment: Good answer. Just wanted to add that in FireFox or Chrome you can also just right-click in the canvas and choose "save image as" from pop-up menu.

Comment: how to save this image in sql database ??

Comment: @AdnanDani Glad the answer could help! Your SQL question is probably a good separate question to ask, since generally that would be done outside of JavaScript. Your click function would probably want to do a POST to a page (written in PHP, .NET, Ruby, etcetera) that then interacts with your database. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8412554/11912 You might also leverage some sort of web service instead. So, it really depends upon the backend logic you're using. Beyond that, storing that string would probably be sufficient, but it of course also depends upon how you're going to use it later.